# Difference of usage between shared and static library

Tags: c++, linux, g++, ftdi

I have a very simple sample of code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include "libMPSSE_spi.h"

int main() {
   uint32 channels = 0;
   std::cout << "erreur = " <<  SPI_GetNumChannels(&channels) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Number of available SPI channels = " << (int)channels << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

That works fine when I link the static libMPSSE, but has an issue with the shared library.

My two commands to build the file are :

```
g++ test.cpp -o test.o -I../../libs/MPSSE -I../../libs/FTDI/linux -L../../libs/MPSSE/linux/x64 -lMPSSE

g++ test.cpp -o test.o -I../../libs/MPSSE -I../../libs/FTDI/linux ../../libs/MPSSE/linux/x64/libMPSSE.a -ldl
```

Both compilation works, but the execution output is not the same. With static linking the library works fine, and with dynamic linking it returns "other error".

Note : I have built both library myself with the provided makefile (object are built before the same way for both libraries):

```
libMPSSE:   $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC)  -o libMPSSE.so -shared $(OBJECTS) -L /MinGW/lib -ldl
    $(AR) rcs libMPSSE.a $(OBJECTS)
```

What could explain the different behavior of both libraries?

Note : in the example they provide with their library, they use the shared library with `dlopen` but if I have the library and header at link time, I shouldnt have to do that?

Note2 : they both use libftd2xx.so and I use this command to run the executable (dynamic and static)

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/WS/Qt/main/LC4/main/libs/FTDI/linux/x64:~/WS/Qt/main/LC4/main/libs/MPSSE/linux/x64 ./test.o
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/WS/Qt/main/LC4/main/libs/FTDI/linux/x64 ./test.o
```

Edit : code that work with shared library (from their example)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "libMPSSE_spi.h"
#include <dlfcn.h>


int main() {

    typedef FT_STATUS (*pfunc_SPI_GetNumChannels)(uint32 *numChannels);
    pfunc_SPI_GetNumChannels p_SPI_GetNumChannels;
    void *h_libMPSSE;

    h_libMPSSE = dlopen("../../libs/MPSSE/linux/x64/libMPSSE.so",RTLD_LAZY);
    if(!h_libMPSSE)
    {
        std::cout <<"Failed loading libMPSSE.so. Please check if the file exists in ";
        std::cout << "the shared library folder(/usr/lib or /usr/lib64)" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    p_SPI_GetNumChannels = (pfunc_SPI_GetNumChannels)dlsym(h_libMPSSE, "SPI_GetNumChannels");

   uint32 channels = 0;
   std::cout << "erreur = " <<  p_SPI_GetNumChannels(&channels) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Number of available SPI channels = " << (int)channels << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your program is loaded and initialized the operating system searches for the required shared libraries in the appropriate directories (e.g. /usr/lib or %WINDIR%\system32)*.

If that library is not present in those directories the application will not run, as the dependency isn't met. Your example probably advises you to use `dlopen` to load the shared library from the same directory your application is in - you might no be able to copy your shared library into the default paths without administrator rights.

* usually you can add more paths to be searched but those are the default ones

Comment: I added a note in my question at the end, the executable finds the library. If it didnt find it, I would have a shell error telling me that it doesnt find it